# Simple language picker

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button

What I am willing to do is a simple language picker. I want to keep selected language in $_SESSION variable, so I have a button in html -

```
<button onClick="language('-value ( 1, 2, 3, ...-')>Language</button>
```

which calls a function

```
 function language(val) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "phplang.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"language": val},
    success: function(data){
   }
  });
 }
```

and phplang.php has the following code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['language']))
  $_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['language'];
?>
```

It doesn't work, since I am a beginner in ajax, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Check your web inspector and see where the post request is going and what is contains

Comment: Post request is successful ,
XHR finished loading: POST     "http://localhost/phplang.php".m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.js:9664m.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:9215language @ (index):37onclick @ (index):83

Comment: And does it contain the language key and right value?

Comment: And $_POST array is empty ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the call to `session_start()` is present in each of your scripts (also in your HTML file - turn it into a .php file first).

Comment: Session is active, html part is already in .php file. Its weird that $_POST is empty :O

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dataType: 'json'` to your jQuery.ajax call:

```
function language(val) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "phplang.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"language": val},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: I think that is not the catch here, I tried it but it doesnt solve my problem.